# Search images from a webcam (Google Goggles style)

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'd like to find images, from a database I have, using a webcam.

Specifically, I'd like to set up a "price kiosk" where people can walk up with an item, put it in front of the camera, and have it search on the database for the price. For seveal reasons (ease of use being the most important) I don't want to use the barcodes in products.

The items are relatively easy to scan (they are, for practical purposes, 2D: they are comic books). I have all the covers already scanned. So what I'd like is some way to take the image from the webcam and use it as a source for the search. Of course the image will be distorted (angle, focus, resolution, lighting, rotation, etc). This isn't a problem for Google Goggles (Google Images really), as I've scanned comic book covers in a number of conditions and it's able to find them.

Now, i've been doing some research. I've seem pretty awesome things done with OpenCV, which makes me think this shouldn't be too difficult to implement. Especially considering my dataset is much smaller (about 2000 different products) than google's.

What am I looking for, specifically? Object detection, recognition, features...?  I'm confused and I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on SIFT: (Scale invariant feature transform)

Comment: thanks. i've been reading a lot lately and finally ended up using SURF because I found several examples based on that.